# How to do fuzzy search in MySQL when separating the characters of the word is needed?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Here is the example of my problem.

I have these data in my database:

```
abcdef
abcdefghi
abcdefghijklmn
```

Now I have this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE name LIKE %abcdf%;
```

If a user types in the word `abcdf` without the `e` in the middle, then how should I write the MySQL sentence in order for the system to select the `abcdef`, `abcdefghi` and `abcdefghijklmn` inside of my database?

Thanks!

Comment: it would make more sense when you make a FULL TEXT index and use `MATCH() AGAINST(..)` ([full text searches](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html)) syntax as `LIKE %abcdf%` syntax can never use a index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will work:

```
select * from Table1 
where soundex(substring(column1,1,4))=soundex(substring('abcdf',1,4));
```

output:

```
column1
abcdef
abcdefghi
abcdefghijklmn
```

check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4e07e/6

Comment: if this works mark it as accepted the green tick others in this forum will get help from it!!!!